# Using SignalR in Window Services

Tags: windows-services, signalr

I am using SignalR to broadcast messages to client browsers via window service.

```
It only works on <http://localhost>
<HubConnection("http://localhost/signalr")>

Change to <http://www.xyz.com> will get an error message: "One or more errors occurred".
<HubConnection("http://xyz.com/signalr")>
```

Are there any settings or additional library required to make it work?

Comment: Please add a full stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any additional components, after all it already works locally.

The 'One or more errors occurred' error is returned when the connection to the remote SignalR resource was not successful.

You can use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and [wFetch](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17275) to troubleshoot such problems